# Why can I not save changes to the "OAuth consent screen" in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am currently unable to save any changes made on the "OAuth consent screen" form in the Google Cloud Platform. The save button is disabled and cannot be used. This behaviour seems to have started, or at least I first noticed it, after the form was submitted to Google for verification. I should note that the consent screen is still in the verification process. Does anyone know why this may be happening?

I have tried to change every field on the form. This has included changing the "application name" and adding and removing the "Scopes for Google APIs" and "Authorised domains". Unfortunately the save button continues to be disabled.

I haven't found anyone on Stack Overflow that has had this issue, nor have I found any official documentation on the matter.

Comment: wait until google completes the verification.

Comment: Is your app internal or public?